# Kubernetes spark-submit

Tags: scala, apache-spark, kubernetes

I am trying to use kuberenets as cluster manger for `spark`. I also want to ship the container logs to `splunk`. Now I do have **monitoring stack** deployed (fluent-bit, prometheus etc)in the same namespace and the way it works is if your `pod` has a certain `environment_variable` it will start reading the logs and push it to **splunk**.
The thing I am not able to find is how do I set a environment variable and populate it

```
bin/spark-submit \
   --deploy-mode cluster \
   --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi \
   --master k8s://https://my-kube-cluster.com \
   --conf spark.executor.instances=2 \
   --conf spark.app.name=spark-pi \
   ....
   ....
   ....
   --conf spark.kubernetes.driverEnv.UID="set it to spark driver pod id" \
   local:///opt/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.4.4.jar
```

Comment: Is `pod id` you are looking for the `pod name`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To configure additional Spark Driver Pod environment variables you can pass additional `--conf spark.kubernetes.driverEnv.EnvironmentVariableName=EnvironmentVariableValue` (please refer [docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.5/running-on-kubernetes.html#spark-properties) for more details).

To configure additional Spark Executor Pods environment variables you can pass additional `--conf spark.executorEnv.EnvironmentVariableName=EnvironmentVariableValue` (please refer [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#runtime-environment) for more details).

Hope it helps.

Comment: I need to `pod_id` to populate with driver **pod_id**. So I was thinking if there is an kubernetes or spark `environment_variable` which I can use to provide the `uid` to the `--conf spark.executorEnv.uid=${SPARK_DRIVER_POD_ID}`

Comment: Could you please explain how do you get `pod_id`? There are ways to do the similar trick with `pod_name` - the name which is displayed when you execute `kubectl get pods`. Also worth to mention that you will need to customize either Spark code (related to Kubernetes) or Docker image and its entrypoint script. Also you can set Driver Pod Name with `spark.kubernetes.driver.pod.name`, and use the same name for ENVs.